# RMStore requestProducts gives exception when requesting products

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, rmstore

I am using [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore) library for IAP (subscription based) and I get exception at this line:     [[RMStore defaultStore] requestProducts:[NSSet setWithArray:_products] success:^(NSArray *products, NSArray *invalidProductIdentifiers) {

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
_products = @[@"NEWSUB01",
              @"NEWSUB06",
              @"NEWSUB12"];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
[[RMStore defaultStore] requestProducts:[NSSet setWithArray:_products] success:^(NSArray *products, NSArray *invalidProductIdentifiers) {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    _productsRequestFinished = YES;


} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Products Request Failed", @"")
                                                        message:error.localizedDescription
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"")
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}];
}
```

below is the requestProducts function and the exception is at line: [_productsRequestDelegates addObject:delegate];

```
- (void)requestProducts:(NSSet*)identifiers
            success:(RMSKProductsRequestSuccessBlock)successBlock
            failure:(RMSKProductsRequestFailureBlock)failureBlock
{
RMProductsRequestDelegate *delegate = [[RMProductsRequestDelegate alloc] init];
delegate.store = self;
delegate.successBlock = successBlock;
delegate.failureBlock = failureBlock;
[_productsRequestDelegates addObject:delegate];

SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:identifiers];
productsRequest.delegate = delegate;

[productsRequest start];
}
```

Same code works in a sample app but does not work in my app.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed that the sample project in [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore) is using non-renewable IAP. For auto-renewable subscription based IAP you should set your store as below:

```
const BOOL iOS7OrHigher = floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1;
_receiptVerifier = iOS7OrHigher ? [[RMStoreAppReceiptVerifier alloc] init] : [[RMStoreTransactionReceiptVerifier alloc] init];
[RMStore defaultStore].receiptVerifier = _receiptVerifier;


_persistence = [[RMStoreUserDefaultsPersistence alloc] init];
[RMStore defaultStore].transactionPersistor = _persistence;
```

Use RMStoreUserDefaultsPersistence for persistence of transaction and also when you refresh or call the receipt it will be persisted automatically according to the [documentation of RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/wiki/Transaction-persistence). Check at the end of the page at the link.