# How to restore only single transaction on restore in app purchase objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am trying to make in app purchase receipt for restore transaction and it restores all of the transactions.How can i make it to restore only one transaction of receipt? Any help please..

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible, or at least post what you have tried so far (code)/what you're trying to do (be more specific). This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help

Comment: Are you using any library for this?

Comment: Yes, i am using RMStore

Comment: Which in app purchase type are you implementing? Is it auto-renewing or non-renewing IAP?

Comment: it is auto renewing IAP...

Comment: Please check my question here and the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433636/rmstore-requestproducts-gives-exception-when-requesting-products

Comment: Please use the following function for restoring your transactions. With RMStore you can restore all the transactions at once: [[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:^(NSArray *transactions) {} Also handle the error case. Please check the sample app for this function. Use this function to check if your purchase is active or not: [[RMAppReceipt bundleReceipt] containsActiveAutoRenewableSubscriptionOfProductIdentifier:@"productid" forDate:[NSDate date]]; Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: Also please update your question with more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour, there is no way to restore a single transaction because Apple's receipt system is based on multiple transactions. Restore transactions are individual transactions too, meaning when you restore purchases, a new transaction with a new [`transactionIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymenttransaction/1411288-transactionidentifier) will be created for the restore. The `original` transaction will be referenced on the [`SKPaymentTransaction`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymenttransaction).

[`restorecompletedtransactions()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions) will synchronize all purchases an iTunes user has made on your app. The purpose is to allow the user to access content previously purchased on the users other devices e.g. a user buys on their iPhone, restores purchases on their iPad, now they can access the content on both devices.

The restored purchase will create a new transaction on the [`SKPaymentQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymentqueue) and you should subscribe to the queue when your app loads. On restore the queue will receive a transaction with a [`SKPaymentTransactionState`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymenttransactionstate) of [`restored`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymenttransactionstate/1411292-restored).

Also [`transactionReceipt()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymenttransaction/1617722-transactionreceipt) is deprecated, so for all intents and purposes you should not use it. Instead use [`appStoreReceiptURL`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1407276-appstorereceipturl).